# why console null block to rc.local starts

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I'm Qt developer. i want my gui application startup when boot finish.

As i see, raspberry developers start gui application from rc.local. I dont know maybe there is another way but i applied this method to my raspberry. And it's working.

Another subject is silent boot...

I can disable aslash_screen, "quiet" word in cmdline.txt but some words always popup.People says change console=tty1 to tty3 but it doesnt work. Last night i found a solution at some website. When i type "console=null" in cmdline.txt, no words popup. That's what i want. But i think this sentence block rc.local starts. Because if rc.local start, my application start.

Any information about that ?
Sorry for bad english

Rasbian(jessie)
4.4.32-v7+

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problems. Keep in mind, Jessie is not Wheezy. To show a splash screen I use fbi. To disable boot messages I had to edit cmdline.txt (console=null). A console=tty3 will work only for Raspbian Wheezy. Now on Jessie with console=null, rc.local won't work. If I switch back console settings in cmdline.txt to tty1 or tty3, rc.local will execute but splash screen gets ugly.

Is there a solution for using splash and rc.local together?

EDIT: Using plymouth instead fbi worked for me. rc.local is running now :-)

Best regards.

Steffen

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that StackExchange is not a discussion forum. Answer should only try to answer the posted question not raise new questions. Please use the "ASK QUESTION" feature to post your own question.

Comment: @massaimara98: try plymouth instead of fbi, then console=tty3 will work for boot splash an rc.local should work too. Best regards. Steffen